# Facebook Signed Request Partial Response

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK to decode a signed request (provided by the JS SDK). The decoded response is sending back the algorithm, code, issued_at timestamp, and user id. In the past, I've been able to pull additional fields from the request (app_data, page and liked boolean), in additional to many more as defined on the Facebook documentation page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Is there any reason that I wouldn't be able to access these additional fields? The application is installed, and living inside of a page tab and I cannot see any reason as to why it wouldn't provide me with more fields, specifically app_data and page.

I've also tried decoding the signed request using the example at the link above, and still receive the same response.

http://cl.ly/image/1p0n1S3S0y0M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK to decode a signed request (provided by the JS SDK).

That means a signed_request you got from FB.login or FB.getLoginStatus, I suppose? You will only get the data that’s described here from one of those, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

The other info you mentioned, page id, whether the user liked the page or not, etc., is only available in the signed_request that Facebook posts to your app on initial load.

Comment: This was the fix. The JS signed_request is different from the one provided via POST (the one that the Facebook SDK can parse). Perfect!

Comment: Just to clarify - can the signed request provided via POST be caught  on the client side? Or can it only be accessed on the server side? (i.e FB PHP SDK needs to be involved)

Comment: JavaScript has no access to POST data, you will need some kind of server side language to access POST data.